# How to access value of a global variable that got updated in a async function in javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await

well i am new to JavaScript and am trying to update a global variable inside an `async function` then i call another function (i.e., after the async function is called) to access the global variable but somehow the global variable isn't updated.

to better explain the problem, see this code.

```js
let a = "";

async function abc() {
   a = "hello";
}

function getA() {
   console.log(a);
}

abc();
getA();
```

However, when I call it, the value of `a` remains unchanged

basically in my code i am trying to read a small text from a file and then save it in a variable after which i use another function to process that text and get output.

Please help !!

Earlier i was using the `async` function to return the text instead of updating the global variable in that case some sort of `promise` used to come up and when i tried to `console.log()` it was fine `it said promise fulfilled` but when i used to access it. It said `undefined`.

Comment: Have you tried using `abc().then(getA)`?

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to be logging the correct thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is two option.

```js
let a

function sleep(ms){
  return new Promise((r) => {
    setTimeout(r, ms)
  })
}

async function abc() {
  await sleep(100)
  a = 'hello'
}

function getA() {
  console.log(a)
}

async function main(){
    await abc()
    getA()
}
main()
console.log('~~~')
```

or

```js
    let a

    function sleep(ms){
      return new Promise((r) => {
        setTimeout(r, ms)
      })
    }

    async function abc() {
      await sleep(100)
      a = 'hello'
    }

    function getA() {
      console.log(a)
    }
    
    abc().then(()=>getA())
    console.log('~~~')
```

first option is wait until a is set.
second option is uses promise..

Comment: i tried the methods and they worked !!!! well i was using .then() in a wrong manner !! Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this:

```js
(async () => {
  let a = "";

  async function abc() {
    a = "hello";
  }

  function getA() {
    console.log(a);
  }

  await abc();
  getA();
})();
```

Comment: thanks for your help too !!! but as i can only mark one of the answers correct so i'll do it for the one that came first :)